# Parsing a string in PHP

Tags: php

My string is like the following format:

> $string =
> "name=xxx&id=11&name=yyy&id=12&name=zzz&id=13&name=aaa&id=10";

I want to split the string like the following:

> $str[0] = "name=xxx&id=11";
>
> $str[1] = "name=yyy&id=12";
>
> $str[2] = "name=zzz&id=13";
>
> $str[3] = "name=aaa&id=10";

how can I do this in PHP ?

Comment: Me thinks you're doing something wrong. Where'd you get that string from?

Comment: If you didn't have duplicate keys (name, id), you could use parse_str()

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all("/(name=[a-zA-Z0-9%_-]+&id=[0-9]+)/",$string,$matches);
```

`$matches` is now an array with the strings you wanted.

**Update**

```
function get_keys_and_values($string /* i.e. name=yyy&id=10 */) {
  $return = array();
  $key_values = split("&",$string);
  foreach ($key_values as $key_value) {
    $kv_split = split("=",$key_value);
    $return[$kv_split[0]] = urldecode($kv_split[1]);
  }
  return $return;
}
```

Comment: +1 another beautiful example of why regular expression is the greatest flavor of noodle soup.

Comment: You should also use `urldecode()` to decode the variables after you parse them.

Answer (score 3):

```
$string = "name=xxx&id=11&name=yyy&id=12&name=zzz&id=13&name=aaa&id=10";
$arr = split("name=", $string);

$strings = aray();
for($i = 1; $i < count($arr), $i++){
    $strings[$i-1] = "name=".substr($arr[$i],0,-1);
}
```

The results will be in $strings

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest using much simpler term

Here is an example

```
$string = "name=xxx&id=11;name=yyy&id=12;name=zzz&id=13;name=aaa&id=10";
$arr = explode(";",$string); //here is your array
```

Comment: won't work if he wants to split parameters of an already defined url

Comment: @Thariama, then OP would ask regarding URL not string

Comment: depends. he then should have asked for an url, but some users mean "url" when they say "string"

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do what you asked, nothing more or less , that's explode('&', $string).

If you have botched up your example and you have a HTTP query string then you want to look at parse_str().

Comment: this won't work because of duplicate strings like `name` and `id`